# I have no idea why this works...I feel everything is telling me it shouldn't Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
let size = 8;
let set = 0;

for (let x = 0; x < size; x++) {
  let line = "";
  for (let y = 0; y < size-1; y++) {
    if (line === "") {
      if(set === 0) {
        line += "+";
        set = 1;
      } else {
        line+="A";
        set = 0;
      }
    }
    if (line[y] === "+") {
      line+="A";
    } else {
      line+="+";
    }
  }
  console.log(line);
}
```

I wrote this to alternate printing A's and plus symbol. Given the number "size" it will print so many lines with alternating A/plus making a checkerboard.

Result:

```
test.js:23 +A+A+A+A
test.js:23 A+A+A+A+
test.js:23 +A+A+A+A
test.js:23 A+A+A+A+
test.js:23 +A+A+A+A
test.js:23 A+A+A+A+
test.js:23 +A+A+A+A
test.js:23 A+A+A+A+
```

My question is:
Why does this work? In my second for loop has size-1 which should be 7. Size is how many chars should be in each line. It just feels wrong and I have gone over the code and can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: But the first time the loop runs it adds two symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first if statement inside that loop (`if (line === "")`) you're adding an extra character if the line isn't initialized yet. The second `if` statement still runs, adding the second character. On subsequent loops, only one character is added.